# Unable to install Gloss on Mac M1

Tags: haskell, cabal

I just learning about Haskell and trying to create Haskell project with ***Cabal***, but when I tried install ***Gloss***, it always return an error

```
-- error
...
ghc: could not execute: opt
cabal: Failed to build OpenGLRaw-3.3.4.1 (which is required by
exe:bouncingball from bouncingball-0.1.0.0). See the build log above for
details.
```

```
-- project.cabal
build-depends:    base ^>=4.14.3.0, gloss
```

anyone can help how could I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I see you've also opened [this](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/7984), cabal issue. I'm afraid, this is really not a cardano question.